# What does "as" mean in "than as that of"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, word-choice

So I was doing the writing question on SAT

the Answer of 22 question is C, but I don't understand what is the "as" for.
[image]

Comment: Your clue is the word _than_. It can only occur in a comparative construction. Look around for a comparison using _as_ and see if the _as_ you're referring to is parallel to it.

Comment: It's about parallelism. You want to compare poems [as the work of an 18th century poet] to poems [as the work of a 3rd century poet]. Answer C does the best job. The way it stands now, you are comparing poems to a poet...not quite right, even if understood in speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Fingal* and *Temora* are better understood ***as** the work of* an eighteenth-century poet  than ***as** that of* a third century one."

In this sentence, the word "that of" replaces the word "the work of" - which means the two clauses run parallel, as John pointed out. This choice is rather formal.

Informally speaking, the other clause can read *"...than **as** a third century one's..."*

Comment: OH, I didn't notice the first as, thank you